# App script don't take filtered pivot table values into account

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, filter, pivot-table

I have a google sheet containing a pivot table whose values are read by another table and on which slicers are applied.
When the slicers are used to filter the value, my app script recompute the values for display in the other table.

The issue is that in my script, the read values are unfiltered despite the view in the sheet being correctly updated regarding applied filters.
The function sheet.getRange(row, column).getValue() gets the unfiltered values of the table and not the filtered values as displayed in the sheet.

So when i apply filters to my pivot table on my sheet, it's well filtered and dispalyed in the sheet but my script seems to not see that the pivot table have been filtered and works on the unfiltered pivot table.

More precisely:
My script creates a pivot table and use its data to fill-in formulas in another table.

For example:

Data Source Table:

| Project | Type | Cost | End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Project 1 | Type_1 | 2600 | 2021 |
| Project 2 | Type_2 | 3500 | 2022 |
| Project 3 | Type_1 | 1200 | 2021 |
| Project 4 | Type_2 | 2350 | 2022 |
| Project 5 | Type_2 | 3350 | 2022 |

Pivot Table:

|  | Col H | Col I |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SUM of Cost | Project_Type | Project_Type |  |
| Project | Type_1 | Type_2 |  |
| Project_1 | 2600 |  | (Row 4) |
| Project_2 |  | 3500 | (Row 5) |
| Project_3 | 1200 |  | (Row 6) |
| Project_4 |  | 2350 | (Row 7) |
| Project_5 |  | 3350 | (Row 8) |

Table with formulas calculated from Pivot Table:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Type_1 | 3800 | (=SUM(H4:H8)) |
| Type_2 | 9200 | (=SUM(I4:I8)) |

I use slicers to filter the pivot table.
Depending on applied filters, it happens that rows or columns disappear as there are no data to display for these rows or columns, which leads to
wrong values for fomulas being calculated on pivot table.

For example:
If I apply a filter on Project_Type to keep only Type_2 on the Pivot table, I get the following result:

Pivot Table:

|  | Col H |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SUM of Cost | Project_Type |  |
| Project_2 | 3500 | (Row 4) |
| Project_5 | 3350 | (Row 5) |

Table with formulas calculated from Pivot Table:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Type_1 | 9200 | (=SUM(H4:H8)) |
| Type_2 |  | (=SUM(I4:I8)) |

So I added a button to relaunch the script which compute formulas on the filtered pivot table.
My problem is that the script is executed on the pivot table data as if it wasn't filtered, whereas the sheet properly displays the filtered pivot table.

In the example:

```js
SHEET.getRange('H4').getValue();
```

returns the value 2600 instead of 3500 as if it was reading the values in the unfiltered pivot table.

How can i get the  filtered pivot table from my script?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Try creating the pivot table your self in the script.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. I have added more details to my description.